# How to get more data from JSON that has multiple pages?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to display all the characters in a list when using a search bar. Right now, I can filter characters but am limited on how many characters can be displayed because the JSON has multiple pages of characters. I have logic to move to the next page but not sure how to implement this with the search bar.

ViewModel

```
import Foundation

@MainActor
class CharacterViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var characters: [Character] = []

    //Don't need an init() method as all properties of this class has default values
    //Using concurrency features
    
    @Published var searchText = ""
    
    
    var filteredCharacters: [Character] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return characters
        } else {
            return characters.filter {
                $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private(set) var maxPages = 1
    private(set) var currentPage = 1
    
    private(set) var hasPreviousPage: Bool = false
    private(set) var hasNextPage: Bool = true
    
    
    struct CharacterResults: Codable {
        var info: Info
        var results: [Character]
        
        struct Info: Codable {
            var pages: Int
            var next: URL?
            var prev: URL?
        }
    }
    



    //MARK: - Fetch all Characters
    
    
    func fetchallCharacters() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=\(currentPage)&name=\(searchText.trimmed())") else {
            fatalError("Bad URL")
        }
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let decodedCharacters = try JSONDecoder().decode(CharacterResults.self, from: data)
            maxPages = decodedCharacters.info.pages
            hasPreviousPage = decodedCharacters.info.prev != nil
            hasNextPage = decodedCharacters.info.next != nil
            
            characters = decodedCharacters.results
        } catch {
             characters = []
        }
    }
    

    
    
    //MARK: - Next page
    func nextPage() async {
      //Update current page and fetch JSON
        currentPage += 1
        await fetchallCharacters()
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Previous page
    func previousPage() async {
       //Update current page and fetch JSON
        currentPage -= 1
        await fetchallCharacters()
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = CharacterViewModel()
    @StateObject var favorites = Favorites()
    
    var previousButton: some View {
        Button("Previous") {
            Task {
                await model.previousPage()
            }
        }
        .disabled(!model.hasPreviousPage)
    }
    
    var nextButton: some View {
        Button("Next") {
            Task {
                await model.nextPage()
            }
        }
        .disabled(!model.hasNextPage)
    }


    //MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
          
            List(model.filteredCharacters){
                   character in
                        
                        NavigationLink {
                            CharacterDetailsView(character: character)
                        } label: {
                            HStack{
                                CharacterRowView(imageUrlString: character.image, name: character.name, species: character.species)
                                
                                if favorites.contains(character) {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                                        .accessibilityLabel("This is a favorite character")
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                }
                            }
                        
                        }
            }
            .searchable(text: $model.searchText, prompt: "Search for a character")
            .onChange(of: model.searchText, perform: { newValue in
                    Task {
                            await model.fetchallCharacters()
                     }
            })
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                previousButton
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                 nextButton
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Characters")
        }//Navigationview
        .task({
            await model.fetchallCharacters()
        })
        .phoneOnlyNavigationView()
        .environmentObject(favorites)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common thing that you'll need to be familiar with working with API endpoints. Usually there are a couple of ways to get data from a paginated API. Most commonly there is a `Pages` value. Looking at the docs there is indeed one of those values on the `Characters`, as seen here. https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#get-all-characters and the property says there are `42` pages.

```
"info": {
    "count": 826,
    "pages": 42,
    "next": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2",
    "prev": null
  },
```

So that means when you call your API endpoint, you need to iterate over it with a function, 42x and add those values to some `[Character]` array or whatever object you're looking for.

To further illustrate this solution, here's your API URL.

```
https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=\(currentPage)&name=\(searchText.trimmed())
```

You're already referencing `currentPage` as a value there. Also if you want all characters, you'd remove the `name` and simply grab ALL of them. This is quite an expensive operation doing it this way so your best bet is to see if you can add additional properties to that URL request to reduce the pages from `42` to something more manageable. Looking further we have this documentation here, https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#filter-characters which tells you how to filter your results. Which may help you reduce the total cost of the results.

In short, fetch all characters immediately, given your possible filters the endpoint accepts, store them into an array, and then filter on that array. The way that you're doing it currently is to fetch each time you search, which will only return that one result, which may be what you want, but the Docs will provide more context on that.

#### Possible Solution

You need to modify this function and it's `API URL` to something like this. Notice I've changed the arguments for `fetchAllCharacters` to include a page that you can pass in. Also I am telling it to check if there is a `.next` page, then recursively call `fetchAllCharacters(page + 1)` which will make the function run again, grabbing more characters. Next instead of setting `characters = results` I'm appending, that way when the function runs again, it doesn't overwrite previous results.

```
func fetchallCharacters(page: Int = 1) async {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=\(page))") else {
        fatalError("Bad URL")
    }
    
    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        let decodedCharacters = try JSONDecoder().decode(CharacterResults.self, from: data)
        maxPages = decodedCharacters.info.pages

        // Append all the characters from this page.
        // MAKE SURE `characters` has been initialized to []
        for result in decodedCharacters.result {
             characters.append(result)
        }

        hasPreviousPage = decodedCharacters.info.prev != nil
        if decodedCharacters.info.next != nil {
             fetchAllCharacters(page: page+1)
        }
    } catch {
         characters = []
    }
}
```

Comment: When I remove the name and utilize string interpolation of \(searchText.trimmed) I only get the data from that current page I'm on. However, when I add that to the url, it does get more characters. I'm just not sure how to display the rest. Do I need to add something to my onChange modifier in my ContentView?

Comment: You need to fetch all the characters, and store them into an array, BEFORE you begin filtering. Then filter on the array of characters you already have.

Comment: I do fetch them all in my ViewModel into an empty array of [Character] and have a computed property for filtering

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it more clear. You're only fetching from `currentPage` in your example, which is why you're not getting any data.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. But the "Next" won't work to move to a new set of characters and when scrolling the first page, it just repeats the characters. When filtering, it displays a few and just repeats on the scroll

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `.info.next` and check to see if it's `nil` if it is, then you need to check your codable structure to ensure that it matches exactly, the response.